# Converting comma separated list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

If I have a list similar to `x <- c("Name,Age,Gender", "Rob,21,M", "Matt,30,M")`, how can I convert to a dataframe where `Name`, `Age`, and `Gender` become the column headers.

Currently my approach is,

```
dataframe <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), nrow=3, byrow=T))
```

which gives me

```
matrix.unlist.user_data...nrow...num_rows..byrow...T.
1                                        Name,Age,Gender
2                                         Rob,21,M
3                                        Matt,30,M
```

and doesn't help me at all.

How can I get something which resembles the following from the list mentioned above?

```
   +---------------------------------------------+
   |    name      |      age      |     gender   |
   |              |               |              |
   +---------------------------------------------+
   |              |               |              |
   |              |               |              |
   |     ...      |       ...     |     ...      |
   |              |               |              |
   |              |               |             ++
   +---------------------------------------------+
   |              |               |              |
   |     ...      |      ...      |   ...        |
   |              |               |              |
   |              |               |              |
   +---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You may used `read.csv` or `read.table` i.e. `read.table(text=paste(x, collapse='\n'), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep=',')`

Comment: Nice. Seems to work. Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `paste` the strings into a single string with `\n` and use either `read.csv` or `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text=paste(x, collapse='\n'), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
data.table::fread(paste(x, collapse = "\n"))
```

> ```
>    Name Age Gender
> 1:  Rob  21      M
> 2: Matt  30      M
> ```